# Approximate order statistics for Half-normal probability plot

Tags: distributions

To construct the half-normal probability plot, plot the absolute values in a certain statistical diagnostic (residual, leverage, Cook distance and others) versus $z_i$ where:

$\displaystyle z_{i}  = \Phi^{-1} \left(\frac{k + n - \frac{1}{8}}{2n +\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

$\therefore$ Applied Linear Statistical Models, (Kutner,Nachtsheim,Neter & Li, 2005) Fifth Edition, Pag 596

or

$\displaystyle z_{i} = \Phi^{-1} \left(\frac{k + n + \frac{1}{2}}{2n +\frac{9}{8}}\right)$

$\therefore$ Generalized Linear Models, (P. McCullagh & J.A. Nelder, 1989) Second Edition,  Pag 407

where  $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

$k$ is the  $k$-th ordered absolute residual

$n$ is the sample size

I could not locate the mathematical justification for the difference of the $z_i$, and more importantly I don't have any intuition about where it comes from.

Comment: You don't seem to have correctly reproduced the second formula (the version I am looking at appears to have $+\frac12$ in the numerator, rather than $-\frac12$). Please check carefully and fix if needed. Please also offer full references if possible (both books have more than one author, for example)

Comment: The first formula is pretty straightforward but I haven't figured out how the second one arises yet. McCullagh and Nelder give no reference for it and it doesn't fit into the same scheme as their full normal suggestion.

Comment: @Glen_b, Thank you very much,, I hadn't seen that had entered the wrong formula. Could you guide me in the first formula?

Comment: Please do not cross-post. It is against SE policy, in part because it causes problems just like this.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to write something shortly; I have something to say about the other case now (though not a definite answer)

Comment: @Glen_b I apologize, I put this question on this site and in the Wolfram Mathematica. But they brought in here, then was repeated. Should I delete this question here? But you answer the other question?

Comment: I'll answer the other one. You can delete this one if you want but it will get deleted eventually anyway without you needing to do anything (and there's at least one reason you might prefer to leave it). Please note that in our [help/on-topic] you're requested not to cross-post to multiple sites -- in part for this exact reason. [If it's definitely on topic at two sites and you're asking at both because you're seeking different *kinds* of answer (e.g. seeking a legal vs a biological perspective so post similar q's to law and biology) that might arguably be okay.]